# need help cleaning my orgs

Tags: apex, cleanup

hello everyone i have a salesforce org and i need to figure out the following :
**custom** objects that are not used.
**fields** in custom objects that are not used.
**apex class/trigger** classes that are not being used.
**aura component** that are not being used.
i wasn't able to find anything useful salesforce optimizer wasn't much of help so is there anything i can use ? some tools or any way i can do it

Answer (score 0):

I used to use a tool called Footprint but not sure this is still accessible. It was more in depth version of a tool called Field Trip, which should still be a great tool for identifying unused custom fields/objects.

There should be more options out there if you keep digging.

Field Trip: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003HSXEEA4

Related Post: [Clearing out fields which are nearly or never used](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12103/clearing-out-fields-which-are-nearly-or-never-used)